# Google Charts - Printing Tables - CSS Print

Tags: css, printing, google-visualization

I am having some issues printing google charts - tables. They are not fitting within the page. Has anyone had some success getting these to print correctly? I have a print.css file setup that I can modify to suit.

Ideally the correct width for landscape would be helpful.

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided (a link to) your print.css... Otherwise it's like using a crystal ball...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **The dimensions of ISO A4 size are:**

   - Portrait: 210mm x 297mm (width x height) -- in PostScript points: 595x842
   - Landscape: 297mm x 210mm (height x width) -- in PostScript points: 842x595
2. **The dimensions for Letter size are:**

   - Portrait: 216mm x 279mm (width x height) -- in PostScript points: 612x792
   - Landscape: 279mm x 216mm (height x width) -- in PostScript points: 792x612

Comment: don't forget to take the printer margins into account! Not so easy though, as they are printer depedent...

Comment: Thanks, I have set in my css print @page { margin: 0.5cm; }. I'm not sure how accurate this is. I have updated the widths and when I view the page using the print css (web developer plugin - firefox) things are close but then I actually view and print it and things are off like my printer is overriding the print.css file. Any ideas?